# Subcribing to the Odometry

Tags: ros, pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a gazebo model which is moved by teleop_keyboard. My model has a node which publishes Odometry values in X and Y and it has nav msgs.. I want to subscribe the turtlesim(topic turtle1/pose) to my model node and make it move in the same coordinates. How can I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248965/subcribing-to-the-odometry/) by [manju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27548/manju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because the `nav_msgs/Odometry` is a different message type from `turtlesim/Pose`, you might have to write yourself a node to convert the two.  Before you do that, check to see if there isn't already a topic publishing the pose you want.

Fortunately one of the values of Odometry is a Pose (see `rosmsg show nav_msgs/odometry`), unfortunately this is a `geometry_msgs/Pose` rather than a `turtlesim/Pose` (use `rosmsg show [msg]` to see what each contains). They are different, most notably the turtlesim Pose does not use a quaternion.

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) with karma: 186 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1